# In Rails, is there a better way to pre-populate an input's value using nested params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, nested, parameters

Let's say I have this in a view:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'foo', params[:foo] %>
```

Of course this pre-populates the input's value using the params' value for 'foo'. However, I'm using some nesting/arrays for the input names:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'filters[person][name]' %>
```

Because params[:filters] and/or params[:filters][:person] may not be present, in order to pre-populate the value, is there a better way to specify the value than the following?

```
<%= text_field_tag 'filters[person][name]', (params[:filters][:person][:name] if params[:filters] && params[:filters][:person])  %>
```

This gets messy really fast when more levels are needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
 (params[:filters][:person][:name] if params[:filters] && params[:filters][:person])
```

With:

```
 params[:filters].try(:[],:person).try(:[],:name)
```

Notice you could build some pretty helper based on the `try` method.

Comment: `try` is a rails method so you should maybe say Rails is the best